# Duplicate Alias error on TS when running script

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to run the below query but getting error as duplicate alias. Could anybody guide me on what I am doing wrong here?

```
 SELECT   c.email , 
             ts.tid , 
             ts.tdate , 
             ts.sr , 
             ts.c_sorigin , 
             ts.subtype , 
             ts.pid , 
             ps.c_msn , 
             ps.c_pgender 
    FROM     c 
    JOIN     ts 
    ON       ts.cid = c.id 
    JOIN     ts 
    ON       ts.ptid = ps.id 
    JOIN     ts 
    ON       pcxref.id = ts.pid 
    WHERE    ( 
                      tdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD') between '2020-01-01' AND      '2020-10-09' 
    AND      l3='12345' 
    AND      lower(tid) IN ( ) 
    ORDER BY c.e , 
             ts.tid , 
             ts.td DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

What part of the error do you not understand?  This is your `FROM` clause:

```
FROM C JOIN
     TS 
     ON TS.Cid = C.id JOIN
     TS 
     ON TS.Ptid = PS.id JOIN
     TS 
     ON PCxref.id = TS.Pid
```

You have `TS` defined *three* times.  Give them each aliases, so you *and* the compiler can distinguish them:

```
FROM C JOIN
     TS ts_c 
     ON ts_c.Cid = C.id JOIN
     TS ts_ps
     ON ts_ps.Ptid = PS.id JOIN
     TS ts_x
     ON ts_x.Pid = PCxref.id
```

You have to fix the references in the rest of the query as well.